# How to disable Skype click to call in Safari?

Tags: safari, skype

When I mouse over a phone number in Safari, it is now a link which tries to call via Skype. I can't see any option within Skype or Safari to disable this. How do I do this?

I'm using latest versions: Safari 8.0.3 and Skype 7.5.

Edit: There is no extension in my Safari for this:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Go to FaceTime -> preferences. There, change "default calling method" to FaceTime. (it might be called a little different, I use a different language)

Answer (score 1):

You must had installed that plug in at one time.

Open your Safari web browser and go to Preferences.

Click Extensions in the menu bar.

Uncheck the Enable Skype Click to Call box.

Comment: I don't see it there, see my updated question for screen clip.